# Why is CGContextDrawImage rotating my image

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

I'm trying to change the color of an area of my `UIImage` with `CGContext` then create a new image from the current state. The original image has the correct orientation but after this, the image turns side ways.

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height);

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, false, originalImage.scale);
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, originalImage.CGImage);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(5,5,100,100));
CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(270));
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very easy question.

Because iOS system has 3 different Coordinate System.

UIKit － y axis direction is down
Core Graphics(Quartz) － y axis direction is up
OpenGL ES － y axis direction is up

The originalImage is create by UIKit and the target image is create by Core Graphics, so it should be upside-down.

If you want get the correct image, you can use:

```
UIImageView* imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 100, 100)];
imageV.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
imageV.layer.borderWidth = 1;
imageV.image = img;
imageV.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(imageV.layer.transform, M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
[self.view addSubview:imageV];
```

Hope it can help you.